# Table with hidden rows that need to toggle jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, toggle

I am building a basic table structure that will have several hidden rows that will populate under the row with the trigger to toggle them. I can't seem to get my toggle trigger to work tho. The rows will all be dynamically created in C# based off the amount of data in our DB. Because of this I am trying to use a counter based trigger to find the rows attached to the trigger link. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Here is my code (P.S. Ignore the inline styles this is just my base to get the triggers working and will be rebuilding it properly in a string variable.):

```
<table border="0">
    <tr style="background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">This is Category</td><td width="370px" align="left">Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here. Additional Details click Errors. Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><a id="a1" href="#">5</a></td><td width="150px" align="center">Feedback</td><td width="100px" align="center">Contact Id</td></tr>            
        <tr class="rpt28_row1" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">12121</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row1"style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">21354</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row1" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">212345</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row1" style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">32456</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">This is Category</td><td width="370px" align="left">Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here. Additional Details click Errors. Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><a id="a2" href="#">5</a></td><td width="150px" align="center">Feedback</td><td width="100px" align="center">Contact Id</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row2" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">12121</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row2"style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">21354</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row2" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">212345</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row2" style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">32456</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">This is Category</td><td width="370px" align="left">Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here. Additional Details click Errors. Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><a id="a3" href="#">5</a></td><td width="150px" align="center">Feedback</td><td width="100px" align="center">Contact Id</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row3" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">12121</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row3"style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">21354</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row3" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">212345</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row3" style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">32456</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">This is Category</td><td width="370px" align="left">Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here. Additional Details click Errors. Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><a id="a4" href="#">5</a></td><td width="150px" align="center">Feedback</td><td width="100px" align="center">Contact Id</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row4" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">12121</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row4"style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">21354</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row4" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">212345</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row4" style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">32456</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">This is Category</td><td width="370px" align="left">Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here. Additional Details click Errors. Criteria for achieving element off service quality is listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><a id="a5" href="#">5</a></td><td width="150px" align="center">Feedback</td><td width="100px" align="center">Contact Id</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row1" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">12121</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row1"style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">21354</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row1" style="display:none; background-color:#fff;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">212345</td></tr>
        <tr class="rpt28_row1" style="display:none; background-color:#F1F5FA;"><td width="120px" align="left">Synopsis:</td><td width="370px" align="left">The contact synopsis is listed here for detail regarding what occured on the call. Contact synopsis listed here.</td><td width="50px" align="center"><img src="Images/category_notachieved_icon.png" alt="" /></td><td width="150px" style="color:#E56A19;" align="center">Comments & Feedback for non achievement displays here. Additions Row can widen to acommodate larger comments.</td><td width="100px" align="center">32456</td></tr>
</table>

 $(document).ready(function(){
    function assignClickHandlerFor(boxNum) {

            console.log('#a' + boxNum);
            $('#a' + boxNum).click(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();

                var $aRow = $(evt.currentTarget); 

                $aRow.find('.rpt28_row' + boxNum).toggle();                  
            });
        }

        var i;

        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            assignClickHandlerFor(i);
        }        
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your javascript to this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    function assignClickHandlerFor(boxNum) {

            console.log('#a' + boxNum);
            $('#a' + boxNum).click(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();

                $('table').find('.rpt28_row' + boxNum).toggle();                  
            });
        }

        var i;

        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            assignClickHandlerFor(i);
        }        
 });​
```

The problem is that you're checking for ancestors of the link. Need to check ancestors of the table instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at this line:

```
var $aRow = $(evt.currentTarget);
```

$aRow cannot find any parent of the $('.rpt28_row' + boxNum) element. so $aRow.find('.rpt28_row' + boxNum) can not be found in the dom.

simply change that line to:

```
var $aRow = $(this).parents('table')
```

and it will work

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ykXYu/)

Comment: This works well too, the answers on here are great examples of how things can be accomplished in different manners. Good stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were using jquery. If so try this code snippet this would do it

```
$('#a' + boxNum).click(function () {
   $('.rpt28_row' + boxNum).toggle()
}
```

Call this when your document is ready.